# jq reading filter from a file results in Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: command-line, jq, quoting

filter.jq
".security = {hideVersionStringsWhenNotLogged: true}"

When trying to apply the filter,
jq --from-file filter.jq a.json

encountering the following error
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1

tried all combinations of single and double quotes to no avail.
Any suggestions?
Thx

Comment: You've got a lot of problems with both the input json and your jq program. Your input json is not valid json (extra unmatched brace after your `impalaSettings` and trailing comma after your last property) and your input jq program is invalid (what is `abtrue`?). It would work if you fixed those issues ([example](https://jqplay.org/s/lZQWRuAqWq))

Comment: In simple words, I just want to know how to use the jq - f option - to read the filter from the file instead of command line

Comment: What you put in your filter file is exactly what you would put from the command line. Just what you currently have is not valid as far as I can see.

Comment: jq '.security = {
"hideVersionStringsWhenNotLogged": true}' a.json - when I execute this - the output is correctly displayed, However, when I try to use the same using jq -f option - syntax error occurs. The filter.jq file contains the filter as is specified above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the filter to be read from a file, do not enclose it in the quotation marks that are needed if the filter is specified on the command line.

So the contents of your `filter.jq` file could look like this:

```
.security = {hideVersionStringsWhenNotLogged: true}
```